# Masking data inside the files in Azure repository

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-repos

I have a need to mask the data, like in Azure Pipelines, but inside the Azure repository files. Is there a way of setting variables, stored apart from the script, as example in Azure pipelines:

```py
variable = $(SecretOne)
```

This is just to avoid the data being stored inside the scripts, in case someone's cloning the project to their local PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each language runtime (node, dotnet, python etc) has its own way of accomplishing this usually through configuration file transformations, environment variables or an env file or the use of a Key Vault.

Azure Repo's doesn't have anything specific built in to substitute secrets or to prevent secrets from being committed into a repo.

You could [setup a pipeline with the GitLeaks task to detect secrets in your repositories](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Foxholenl.Gitleaks) so you can take action, but when this happens, the secret is already committed to Azure Repos and you'll need to recycle what secret (password reset, revoke, deny-list).

Comment: Maybe this is not relevant to this topic, but I found a way to encrypt files, store them in Azure repositories and pull this with 3rd party tool. 3rd party tool supports built in decryption with this tool `npm install -g cryptify` after which I run the scripts. A workaround to say.

Comment: Yes that works too. But if the decryption key is lost (or effectively every time a team member leaves the company) you should rotate all the secrets.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I would of course add the Azure Keyvault here. :) That way we can store the secrets too, but we are getting off-topic here.